# Access a custom field type value set in preSave, in hook_entity_presave()

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

I have a custom field type, that generates a value in a [preSave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!FieldItemBase.php/function/FieldItemBase%3A%3ApreSave/8.2.x) hook.

```
class AutoGeneratedItem extends FieldItemBase implements FieldItemInterface
{
  // ** Snip **

  public function preSave()
  {
    // Set value here
  }

  // ** Snip **
}
```

Apart from that, I have a custom module, which has it's own presave hook.
Where I would like to use the auto generated value of the custom field type.

```
function HOOK_entity_presave($entity)
{
    $autoValue = $entity->auto_generated_field->value;
}
```

However, in the presave hook the value of the auto generated field is still NULL, how can I make my presave hook fire after the preSave in the custom FieldType?

Comment: Since your second module obviously depends on your first module, you could [implement a custom hook](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201032/how-do-i-create-and-use-a-custom-hook) and invoke that from the first `preSave()`. This makes sure the first module calls the second one (it will always run when requested). (The linked example is not really a great source, but the suggestion remains valid ;) )

Comment: To be clear, preSave isn't a hook, it's default functionality to the Field Plugin System, i've added a link to the function in the api documents in my post above (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!FieldItemBase.php/function/FieldItemBase%3A%3ApreSave/8.2.x).